# Common emmiter amplifier collector current selection when using a current source to achieve symmetrical output swing

Tags: transistors, bias, biasing

I know how to bias a common emmiter configuration when using resistors, my main interest is biasing the transistor in a way that maximum symmetrical output swing is achieved, when using resistors, this is easily accomplished by placing the Ic current quiescent point at the middle of the AC load line, which is quite simple when using only resistors.

However, when using a current source to bias the transistor, such as the following circuit:

[image]

How can I find analitically the optimum collector current to bias the transistor at the center of the AC load line in order to achieve maximum symmetrical output swing?

Comment: Perhaps if you spent just a little bit of your time talking about why you want this arrangement and why you expect it to work in a certain way, it could help. Normally, the CE arrangement uses the BJT something like an emitter-follower to vary the emitter current, which then varies the collector current and gets you your voltage output. In this case, Q1 looks more like a cascoded BJT (that oddly has a signal at its base) and I'm not sure how you expect that to perform.

Comment: I want this arrangement specially because I can achieve a higher input impedance than with a normal CE amplifier. Its one of the biasing techniques I've seen on books like Sedra Smith.

Comment: Yes, there is no question that it may increase the input impedance as it "stiffens" the emitter leg. But the whole point in the usual CE arrangement is to *vary* the collector current by varying the emitter current. If you want to stiffen the input impedance, the usual method is to bootstrap the base divider using an added resistor and capacitor. This particular arrangement doesn't look workable to me. I see a base and emitter for Q1 moving up and down with signal, with its collector staying put. Not much value to it. But then I'm certainly more ignorant than Sedra and Smith.

Comment: Yes you are right, I should have used bootstrap to increase the input impedance, even more than this arrangement. I was wondering on how to select the best bias point when using this sort of arrangement because some books mention it, but they dont explain which current should be chosen, and it makes a lot of a difference.

Comment: Think about the variation in \$\beta\$ for a given BJT family and manufacturer. It ranges over temperature and part and probably time, as well. You want some kind of predictable result for your circuit. The bootstrap resistor carries the DC bias current for the BJT (the input capacitor provides the AC base drive current variation around that.) Variations in the DC bias current through the bootstrap resistor will move the quiescent point around. You have to decide how much of that to tolerate. There isn't a hard and fast rule here.